# ¿Puedo guardar en otra ruta la BD SQLite en android en lugar de /Data/...?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlite3

Me gustaría guardar la BD de mi aplicacion movil en otra carpeta que no fuera la ruta normal de /data/.., por ejemplo en la sdcard en una ruta que yo pueda especificar.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes especificar el path del almacenamiento externo:

```
String nombreDirectorio = "basededatos/";
String nombreDB = "datos.db";

String ruta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +  File.separator + nombreDirectorio + nombreDB;
```